# Caliburn Micro event on view/viewmodel closing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

My application contains some objects that need to be cleaned up when the view closes, how do get caliburn to fire an event when it's closing the view? Is this even possible? Specifically it's some quartz.net triggers and schedules that need to be stopped once the application closes but I can't find anything to that end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Quartz.NET runs inside your process, so it will be stopped anyway when your process ends

Second: You can make your ViewModel implement `IClose` and put your code inside `TryClose` or derive from `Screen` and override `OnDeactivate` and put the code there.